# Can SpringBoot-Kafka application play both consumer and producer

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

In this app, we are consuming message processing it and then again forwarding it to other consumer, so can any one please share a possible way to do this,
it'll be great if you can share some example too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Kafka project have `@SendTo` annotation just for this purpose, that is making your consumer also produce messages [read docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#annotation-send-to)

Alternatively, You can use a single consumer to receive message from `firstTopic` and add a `kafkaTemplate` into it
So that, after processing it will send a message to `secondTopic`. Below is a simple example of this consisting only a producer and a consumer.
For full example reference with config classes(only for basic producer-consumer example) see [here](https://www.codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-consumer-producer-example.html)

Producer

```
package com.codenotfound.kafka.producer;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;

public class Sender {

  private static final Logger LOGGER =
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sender.class);

  @Autowired
  private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

  public void send(String topic, String payload) {
    LOGGER.info("sending payload='{}' to topic='{}'", payload, topic);
    kafkaTemplate.send("firstTopic", payload);
  }
}
```

Consumer

```
package com.codenotfound.kafka.consumer;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;

public class Receiver {

  @Autowired
  private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

  private static final Logger LOGGER =
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);



  @KafkaListener(topics = "firstTopic")
  public void receive(String payload) {
    LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", payload);

    //To do processing and get generate payload
    String payload2 = someprocessingLogic(payload);
    kafkaTemplate.send("secondTopic", payload);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think kafkaTemplate.send("firstTopic", payload); this should have topic rather than "firstTopic".

Comment: Yes, if you are using `"topic"` as your topic name, in example `"firstTopic"` is used for the topic name.